# Get latest date from oracle with java

Tags: java, oracle11g

I want to fetch latest date from records in oracle database by using Java.

Example:

```
String query = "Seclect LATEST_INSERT_DATE from test";
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Also need latest date with latest time.

like:

### ID DATE         MONTH   YEAR

34 04-DEC-13    Jan 1980
35 04-DEC-13    Feb 1980

Now, i have to fetch latest one .
Please give me the oracle Query.

Please help me. any help would be appreciable.

Comment: My problem is : i want to fetch latest date from all the dates.

Comment: Provide at least the table definition

Comment: LATEST_INSERT_DATE is column name or what?

Comment: try MAX(LATEST_INSERT_DATE)

Comment: its a column name.... any java logic will also be good for me.

Comment: you've got the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the max 'INSERT_DATE_FIELD':

```
String query = "Select MAX(INSERT_DATE_FIELD) from test";
```

Comment: yes it's working. Really you make my day.

Comment: its working fine.. but i have to fetch on the basis of latest time as well

Comment: Make a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

String query = "select * from (Select * from test order by INSERT_DATE_FIELD desc) where rownum = 1

or Select * from test order by INSERT_DATE_FIELD desc and in java part use if(rs.next())

and take only the first row.

Comment: Not working .. getting missing expression error .. i am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: @ArvindVishwakarma i changed my answer